# In Rails, can you get a file contents without rendering it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In a model, I want to get a file's contents without rendering it. Say the file is a .erb file. I want to store its contents in a database, and then later on, I'll evaluate the string so that it replaces the variables in the .erb file with actual values.

Is there a method like render_to_string that doesn't actually evaluate the .erb part?

Answer (score 1):

I'll ignore any reason you would want to do something like this. Ok so, you're looking to read files, this is done with plain Ruby:

```
File.read 'path/to/file'
```

That's how you read any file in Ruby. For a view in Rails you'd have to specify the path:

```
File.read Rails.root.join('app/views/some_view_dir/your_view_file.erb')
```

Just replace `some_view_dir/your_view_file.erb` with your actual view.

Reading files this way gets just the raw content, and you can do this with any file type.